# Can older iOS devices run apps built with newer versions of the iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

If I build an app with the (default) iOS 5.1 SDK in XCode, and distribute it to the appstore, will users with, let's say, an iPhone 3G, be able to download and run the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let me answer you a little more correctly than Omar did:

In XCode, you can define both the SDK you're using to compile your app (should always be "latest" SDK, currently 5.1) and the Minimum OS Version that you're app will run with/at.
You should always test your app on all (Major) OS Versions starting from the defined minimum OS version.
You can react in your code to the current iOS Version and use different features depending on the currecnt version with a statement like:

```
if ([UIDevice systemVersionValue] >= 4.2f) {
 // code for OSes at least as new as 4.2
} else {
  // code for older OSs
}
```

If you want maximum exposure for your app, you should try to support all iOS Versions still supported by Apple. Currently, that's iOS 4.0 and newer, AFAIK. Given the very high update rate of iOS Users, everything older doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for the deep answer, was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what features you include in your app: if you use features that are only available in iOS5 such as `UIPageController`, then no, they will not be able to run it. However, if you don't use any feature of iOS 5, then it will most likely be ok.

Comment: Ah ok. Seems legit. I was just wondering because at android i have to explicitly advice eclipse for which android version my app is aimed!

Comment: You still have to do that, the relevant build setting is the "Deployment target". This defines the minimum OS version you support. The SDK version should always be the latest.

Comment: Thank you. Last question: which iOS version is preferable for a wide distribution? My app is standard... Retrieve and send data, and use of the camera api... (preferable android version is 2.2 because its installed on the most android devices)

Comment: @Mike Weller thank you. Last question: which ios version is preferable for a wide distribution? My app is a standard one... Retrieve and send data and use of the camera api. (preferable android version is 2.2 because its the most installed one)